# In the run() method, why is counter a random number?

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't understand why the output for counter is a different random number every time. When I print out counter in the run() method it is 100000 every time but then when I comment that statement out it gives a random number.

```
    public class Answer extends Thread {
      private static int counter = 0;
      private static final int THREADS = 4;
      public static final int COUNT = 100000;
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Answer[] threads = new Answer[THREADS];
         for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Answer();
            threads[i].start();
         }
         try {
            for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
               threads[i].join();
            }
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
         System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
      }
      public void run() {
         for (int i = 0; i < COUNT/THREADS; i++) {
             counter++; 
             //System.out.println(counter);
         }
} }
```

Comment: Why on earth did you think that making 'counter' a static would be a good idea?  Do you routinely declare vars as static?  Why did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

The operation

```
 counter++
```

in your thread code isn't thread-safe. Your threads are stepping on each others' operations.

By sheer luck, the thread-safe parts of println are synchronizing your threads' operations well enough to prevent the adverse interactions on your static variable. When you comment out the println call, you lose that lucky sync.

You can use a synchronized variable if you need to use something like this for production.

Answer (score 1):

These are the following two reasons.

- counter++
- Thread scheduling.

**counter++**

It is not a thread safe.

Ex.
Counter = 0.
Thread 1 & Thread 2 try to increment the value at the same time. Both will get the value from main memory. Increments in thread memory . So now counter is 1. Update in main memory to 1 instead of 2.
You can overcome this using `volatile` or `AtomicInteger`.

**Thread Scheduling:**

Thread scheduling is done by OS. There is no guarantee in order. Even if you submit thread1&thread2&thread3 in same order. It may run on different order.

Answer (score 0):

Your counter variable is static and shared between all the threads you create and each thread is changing the counter on its own. Try removing 'static' from counter variable.

This:

```
private static int counter = 0;
```

To this:

```
private int counter = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`counter` is a shared variable among threads that is not protected by any lock or synchronization, so the `counter++` statements on the various threads will "trample into each other" in unpredictable ways.  Presumably the `println` introduces enough delay to counteract that, though this can't be guaranteed 100%.  What are you **trying** to accomplish...?!